# Using profile for people to submit activities

Tags: profile, activities, permissions

How can I create a data entry profile that creates an activity?

Example: We train peer leaders, who then meet with mentees. We'd like them to submit their meeting information (e.g. duration, # of attendees, brief description) as an activity (e.g. type = 'peer leader meetings with mentees') that would be associated with the peer leader contact.

Similarly, we'd like to have activity types 'gave informational talk', 'served on a panel', 'participated in outreach event', etc.

The reason I'm asking about doing it as a profile is that we wouldn't want them to be able to view contact participation history, etc.- just to complete and submit the activity.

Or is there a different method you'd recommend to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal then you can use webform and webform civicrm module. This modules allows to create front end forms using Civi fields and also provide ability to perform actions  when form is submitted like creating activity, relationships, contribution etc.

For wordpress you can use caldera and civicrm caldera plugins which is similar to drupal webform.

Thanks

Pradeep